# Caching attributes with id(self), any better solutions?

Tags: python, caching, python-3.x

I'm trying to cache attributes to get a behavior like this:

```
ply = Player(id0=1)
ply.name = 'Bob'

# Later on, even in a different file
ply = Player(id0=1)
print(ply.name)  # outputs: Bob
```

So basically I want to retain the value between different objects if only their `id0` is equal.

Here's what I attempted:

```
class CachedAttr(object):
    _cached_attrs = {}

    def __init__(self, defaultdict_factory=int):
        type(self)._cached_attrs[id(self)] = defaultdict(defaultdict_factory)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance: 
            return type(self)._cached_attrs[id(self)][instance.id0]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        type(self)._cached_attrs[id(self)][instance.id0] = value
```

And you'd use the class like so:

```
class Player(game_engine.Player):
    name = CachedAttr(str)
    health = CachedAttr(int)
```

It seems to work. However, a friend of mine (somewhat) commented about this:

> You are storing objects by their id (memory address) which is most likely going to leaks or get values of garbage collected objects from a new one which reused the pointer. This is dangerous since the id itself is not a reference but only an integer independent of the object itself (which means you will most likely store freed pointers and grow in size till you hit a MemoryError).

And I've been experiencing some random crashes, could this be the reason of the crashes?
If so, is there a better way to cache the values other than their `id`?

**Edit:** Just to make sure; my `Player` class inherits from `game_engine.Player`, which is not created by me (I'm only creating a mod for an other game), and the `game_engine.Player` is used by always getting a new instance of the player from his `id0`. So this isn't a behavior defined by me.

Comment: Do you want a new object with the same attributes, or do you want to retrieve the existing object with that `id`? (Similar to how `logging.getLogger` works.)

Comment: @chepner new object with the same attributes.

Comment: `id(self)` should always be the same value for the same object... that said it is probably better to cache on its values rather than its id ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `__init__`, look at `__new__`. There, look up the unique object in dict and return that instead of cerating a new one. That way, you avoid the unnecessary allocations for the object wherever you need it. Also, you avoid the problem that the different objects have different IDs.

Comment: This is what I did at first, but whenever the level changes in the original game, the existing instance of the `game_engine.Player` class (and therefore my `Player` instance too) no longer works, not sure why but that's how the actual game works. I always need to get a new instance of the player between all the games, therefore I'm only trying to store the attribute's values, not the actual instances.

Comment: So sometimes it's supposed to be the same and sometimes not? This sounds like a pretty weird way of doing things, in particular hard-coding this into the `Player` class. I foresee that you will not make your code any cleaner and better maintainable that way.